# DependencyProperty for TextBox gives compile time error (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, dependency-properties

I have a textbox with a DependencyProperty, Code looks like this

```
<UserControl
x:Class="Projectname.Controls.Editors.EditTextControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:ui="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid>
    <TextBox  PlaceholderText="I'am Active"   HasError="{Binding IsInvalid, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Height="80" Width="300"  x:Name="txtActive"  Text="{Binding TextValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" ></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

```
  public sealed partial class EditTextControl : UserControl
{
    TestViewModel TV = new TestViewModel();
    public EditTextControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = TV;
    }

    public bool HasError
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(HasErrorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HasErrorProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is a dependency property that will indicate if there's an error. 
    /// This DP can be bound to a property of the VM.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HasErrorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HasError", typeof(bool), typeof(EditTextControl), new PropertyMetadata(false, HasErrorUpdated));


    // This method will update the Validation visual state which will be defined later in the Style
    private static void HasErrorUpdated(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        EditTextControl textBox = d as EditTextControl;

        if (textBox != null)
        {
            if (textBox.HasError)
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(textBox, "InvalidState", false);
            else
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(textBox, "ValidState", false);
        }
    }
}
```

All looks good to me, But on compile-time itself, it's giving these errors.

```
The property 'HasError' was not found in type 'TextBox'.
The member "HasError" is not recognized or is not accessible.
```

Can anyone please point out what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HasError** is a property on the **EditTextControl** user control, not on the **TextBox**.
If you want to add a custom property to the TextBox class, you use an [Attached Propert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/custom-attached-properties)y not a Dependency property.